# Bitcoin i have been asked to send money for a private key

Tags: blockchain, private-key, verification, deposit

Hi i have been asked to send money for funds that are nonspendable to receive a private key to unlock it, it's from bitcoin investing. How safe is this as i'm worried i wont receive the payment. It's currently sitting in my blockchain wallet account and it displays the funds as nonspendable until unlocked with a private key

Comment: **This is a scam!** There is no such thing as 'needing to pay to unlock a private key', this is just some nonsense the scammer made up to get you to send them more money. Cut your losses, do NOT send anymore BTC to this person.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get a private key for this address](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/74362/how-can-i-get-a-private-key-for-this-address) - a common scam used for many years to steal money from people new to Bitcoin. Many many examples here. Read these other questions from people cheated in the same way as you.

Answer (score 4):

This is most likely a scam! there have been a similar question recently [Why do I have to deposit BTC as missing turnover](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/90981/why-do-i-have-to-deposit-btc-as-missing-turnover)

There is no need to send bitcoin or money to receive a private key or unlock a bitcoin wallet, be careful.

Comment: It's to unlock nonspendable funds says i need a private key to access it

Comment: If you need a private key there is plenty of free option to generate one, this site for example https://www.bitaddress.org you should still read and understand how to do it securely though

Comment: @Jay39 it's a scam. this is not how bitcoin transfers take place. they won't give you anything even after you send them more money.

Comment: It is not sitting in your blockchain wallet account. That's why you can't spend it. It is sitting in someone else's account which you are watching. Whoever set this up is trying to trick you into thinking that you have some claim or ownership over these funds. But you don't. They're not in your account at all, they're in someone else's account.