# "Needed Turnover" / "Missing Turnover" - How to get my money out?

Tags: blockchain.info, client, fraud

Contact Information: contact@securitycrypto.info
General information support: info@securitycrypto.info
Support and online transaction search with full and detailed information: support@securitycrypto.info
Does anyone have dealings with these people?

I made a mistake when I copy and paste my wallet with 6+ bitcoins, now I am told I have to activate to wallet that has my coins in but it has come back and said there is a turnover 2.2 bitcoins with is almost 20 gran. I am being to put out the 20 gran and I would have my money out in 20 min.

I received the following message from them:

> By default HASH with zero balance and zero turnover,
> The verification of such a wallet requires by default  BTC 6.43137963
> Please note!
> That you may not have to verify the amount previously registered.
> [registered amount - an amount involved in turnover transactions]
> [unregistered amount - an amount that has not previously participated in turnover operations]
> You can familiarize yourself with it by checking operations inside of your HASH.
> We remind you, that the blockchain system is fully automatic and public open.
> Therefore, it is not necessary to have an amount of  BTC 6.43137963
> for verification of your HASH
> Needed turnover: BTC 2.20968
> When generated wallet attached to exchanger,
> Balance of BTC 8.64105963 will be available to use and carry out any further transactions.
> We remind you one more time,
> That sum is already inside the wallet.
> As soon as verification is completed,
> You are going to be the only owner of these funds,
> And can carry out further transactions.
> Blockchain system is a fully automatic system and gives you a full guarantee and safety,
> When you follow instructions and protocol.
> Balance:          BTC 6.43137963
> Missing turnover: BTC 2.20968
> Please note!
> After activation and verification, the amount of BTC 8.64105963 will be shown automatically.
> When a wallet will be added to the exchanger you can carry out any transaction on your behalf.

The above is my email from  support@securitycrypto.info telling about the turnover.

Thank you for helping.
The 6 + bitcoins are in our name and all the security has been completed by the Blockchain. And I just had to copy and paste the wallet ID. Made a mistake and the money went to the wallet with the v at the end and I was sent a screenshot of the wallet with money.
Let us know if you have any additional questions.

Answer (score 5):

What you describe is absolutely typical of what happens when someone inexperienced or relatively new to Bitcoin gets tricked by criminal confidence tricksters.

The victim is often contacted by someone offering to help them invest money in Bitcoin and earn large profits in a few days or weeks.

The victim sends money to be invested in Bitcoin, but the criminal may claim not to have received them. The criminal may blame the victim for using the wrong address and tell them it can be sorted out by creating a new wallet and paying in more money. The criminal guides the victim in creating new wallets in such a way that the criminal has the real control, not the victim.

Then the criminal extracts more money by claiming that extra fees are required. The criminal invents various reasons why the fees are required. throwing in words like turnover or miner or release is typical.

There are variations where someone gets confused by some Bitcoin problems and posts messages on social media asking for help. They then receive private messages (PMs, email etc) from criminals offering help. The criminals gain the confidence of the victim and go on to trick them out of more money.

> **How to get my money out?**

Once you have given your money to criminal confidence tricksters there is no way you or anyone else can get your money back.

You can report the fraud to your local police. They are very unlikely to be able to help retrieve money but it is probably best that they know the extent of such crime.

> **securitycrypto.info Does anyone have dealings with these people?**

The domain name securitycrypto.info was created last November and doesn't have a website. That doesn't make me feel they are trustworthy.

A quick web-search shows that email-address, support@securitycrypto.info, mentioned by other people being tricked out of money in the same way.

You are much better off getting help in a public forum (like this one) - don't reply to direct private messages offering help - they are almost all from criminals wanting to trick you.

> **I am told I have to activate to wallet that has my coins in**

Lies, typical of criminal scammers and confidence-tricksters.

> **but it has come back and said there is a turnover 2.2 bitcoins with is almost 20 gran. I am being to put out the 20 gran and I would have my money out in 20 min.**

Typical nonsense used by criminals to confuse and panic their victims.

---

See also

- [Why do I have to deposit BTC as missing turnover](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/90981/13866)